# php calculate values from a loop

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I can't get my head around this.
I have a `csv`-file containing companynames and a certain value.

I run a script that get's the companyname and value from the `csv`.
A company can contain multiple values.
Here's what it looks like

```
[company1][123]
[company1][65456]
[company1][435]
[company1][234235]
[company2][65464]
[company2][53543]
```

What I want to do is get every value from every separate company and calculate the `sum` of all values from that specific company.

So I tried this:

```
foreach($data as $companies){
    $company = $companies['name'];
    $value = $companies['value'];
    if ($company == 'company1'){
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

`$data` is the array with values from the `csv`

For testing purposes I have manually written a companies name in the `if` statement but this should be dynamically loaded from the `$data`-array.

After this it should calculate the `sum` of all values.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: you need all companies sum or sum of each company??

Comment: No the sum of the values belong to that company

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
$arr_sum = [];

foreach ($data as $companies) {
    $company = $companies['name'];
    $value = $companies['value'];

   if (!isset($arr_sum[$company])) {
       $arr_sum[$company] = 0;
   }

   $arr_sum[$company] += $value;
}
```

> **demo:** http://ideone.com/KXGCOd

Comment: Dude... Like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if I understand well your issue, this should work.

```
$data = [
['name' => 'company1', 'value' => 123],
['name' => 'company1', 'value' => 65456],
['name' => 'company1', 'value' => 435],
['name' => 'company1', 'value' => 234235],
['name' => 'company2', 'value' => 65464],
['name' => 'company2', 'value' => 53543]
];
$result = 0;
foreach($data as $companies)
{
    $company = $companies['name'];
    $value = $companies['value'];
    if ($company == 'company1')
    {
        $result += $value;
    }
} 
echo $result;
```

HOWEVER! PHP is not very powerful when it comes to calculations, especially 
 when embedded in a loop. If your companies has couple of different values each and you have couple of companies too, then fine. But if your file contains thousands of companies with many values, then your script will be very limited (think to increase/deactivate server time out). I would suggest to use python for your specific case, it would be much faster, easier and more important: it will scale :)